# FileZilla: able to connect via SFTP, but failed to list directories

Tags: sftp, filezilla

I used FileZilla to connect to one of my Linux servers via the SFTP protocol, but got below error stack trace.

```
Status: Connecting to <server_ip>...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=5
Command:    keyfile "C:\ruifeng_ibm.ppk"
Command:    open "root@<server_ip>" 22
Status: Connected to <server_ip>
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

On the server when I ran `lsof -i`, I was able to see the established `sshd` connection.

```
sshd    12333 root    3u  IPv4 109406      0t0  TCP <server_hostname>:ssh-><workstation_ip>:54315 (ESTABLISHED)
```

How could the directories not be listed when the connection is successful? No idea how to debug either.

Comment: I don't understand why the question got a downvote. Appreciated it if the person could have given a comment on why.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a silly problem.

I put below welcome message in the `.bashrc` file.

```
 echo -e "\n\nHello Ruifeng...Welcome to the Arena! \n@>>------>---->>"
```

Either it contained some illegal characters FileZilla does not honor, or it's completely not supported by FileZilla. Too lazy to further dig in. After removing this message, the connection worked and the directories got listed.